# number_to_currency with ruby argument as number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to make one of my hashes to display as currency. I am not sure if I should do this inline, or in my controller. I saw this:

so I tried to inline like this:

```
  <div class="price">
    <h2>
      <%= number_to_currency(<%= product[:price] %>) %>
    </h2>
  </div>
```

that did not work.

then I tried this in my controller:

```
 :price =>  number_to_currency(50.0)
```

what is the syntax for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="price">
    <h2>
      <%= number_to_currency(product[:price]) %>
    </h2>
  </div>
```

This should work